# Maintaining Server-Sent Events (Azure/fetch-event-source) during Mobile Web User Inactivity

Tags: google-chrome, fetch-api, service-worker, web-worker, server-sent-events

I'm working with Server-Sent Events (SSE) using the Azure fetch-event-source library for my react web app that has a retry interval of 30 seconds. Everything works great when the user is on the mobile web page(iOS & Android). However, I'm facing an issue when the user's browser goes out of focus or the mobile device is inactive for a few minutes(closing the browser but not killing it).

I logged a `connection made` everytime a connection/call is made `onopen`, and it stops going when Chrome or Safari browser seemingly suspends it.

I want to ensure that the SSE connection persists and continue to retry every 30s even when the user is not actively interacting with the page or when the mobile device is in the background.

I've tried setting the `openWhenHidden` parameter to true for the fetchEventSource method which helps persists the connection when the desktop browser tab is inactive. It does not, however, help with mobile web user.